# Splitting a values as list from a string using ansible filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How to convert the above string to the list of comma separated strings using ansible filter.I need like this var2 , so that i can loop it and use those values.

```
  Expected:

      var2: [arn:aws:sds:ABCDEFGHI123456, arn:aws:sds:HRTYUIOPE89012345]"

  Input:
      var1:"arn:aws:sds:ABCDEFGHI123456arn:aws:sds:HRTYUIOPE89012345"
```

thansk!!!

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
- name: play1
  hosts: all
  vars:
    x: "arn:aws:sds:ABCDEFGHI123456arn:aws:sds:HRTYUIOPE89012345"
  tasks:
    - name: task1
      debug:
        msg: "arn:{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ x.split('arn:') }}"
```

Comment: But it will separate after : alone,here I need to fetch values which start with arn followed by that value

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I have edited my answer. Hope it helps!